# Identity Server Calling It's own configuration endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have two clients requiring authentication.

One client is a spa that uses implicit flow, and the other is a direct system integration that uses the client credentials flow for login.

For some reason, when my client credentials client calls my API, my Identity Server app tries to call the `.well_known/openid-configuration` endpoint on itself.

The call makes no sense, seeing that it is the server which is serving the configuration in the first place that is trying to call an endpoint in itself.

Is there a way to populate this configuration without having identity server call its own endpoint?

Below is a snippet with my Identity server configuration.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Bearer";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        }).AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = openIdConnectConfig.SignInScheme;
            options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;

            options.Authority = openIdConnectConfig.Authority;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

            options.ClientId = clientConfig.First(x => x.ClientId == "spa_app").ClientId;

            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:8080";
        }).AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = openIdConnectConfig.Authority;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

            options.ApiName = "api_client";
        });
```

Comment: Is the code you've shown from your IdentityServer implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to prevent this behaviour (at least not unless you attempt to implement the `IConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectOptions>`). This is actually an intended behaviour because you have your web app & identity server hosted on the same app. The call to its own endpoint is due to the `AddOpenIdConnect` authentication scheme which when you start up the app will fetch the identity provider metadata information for JWT validation purposes.

You could theoretically go and implement `IConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectOptions>` that does not call the `MetadataAddress` endpoint and set that in the authentication scheme builder.

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            ...
            ConfigurationManager = myCustomConfigurationManager,  //You would need to implement this
            ...
        })
```

This is the culprit that's responsible for the call to the `MetadataAddress` endpoint which by default is `authorityUri + /.well_known/openid-configuration`.

I would advise against doing so because in the end you will need the identity provider metadata information anyway so would have to snapshot and store it locally or something like that.

Comment: I don't know if it's calling it at startup, but it does call it when I hit my API controller with the client credentials flow. For my SPA with implicit flow it doesn't happen.

Comment: Actually it's not calling the endpoint on startup, because it would crash my whole application. On our network, requests like these, accessing a private sever via a public host does not work.

Comment: @Tjaart It depends how the authentication middleware is implemented. I can see why it would not call on startup because it can cache the discovery document info after it tries to fetch it first time. My point still stands even if it's not calling at startup.

Comment: I've found another solution that allows this. I just thought it was strange and unusual for it to call an endpoint on itself.